# How can I get the WindowClient id of the current window?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

From inside a service worker, I can do `await clients.matchAll({includeUncontrolled: true})` to get a list of the current windows that the service worker can control and  communicate with. For example, when I do that and I have 2 windows opened, I get an array with 2 WindowClient objects that looks something like this:

```
WindowClient {visibilityState: 'visible', focused: true, url: 'http://localhost:3000/', id: 'f56e10ac-6a7c-44ca-8322-11165a45eb4b', type: 'window'}
WindowClient {visibilityState: 'hidden', focused: false, url: 'http://localhost:3000/', id: 'b1be5170-8e98-4927-a53b-48c4752a82f1', type: 'window'}
```

It is noteworthy that each window has an id there. Now, my question is, from code that runs inside a window, is it possible to somehow get hold of that id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With complicity of the `ServiceWorker`, and the `Client` or `WindowClient`, yes.

You can get the `fetchEvent.resultingClientId` in `fetch` handler and communicate that ID to the client in the headers, using `postMessage()`, or other means.

Comment: Yep, realized if I do a postMessage from the main window, the id of the window will be available in the service worker event handler as event.source.id. So the main window can ask the service worker "who am I?" and the service worker can answer. A bit hackish, but it works...

Comment: There are multiple ways to achieve the requirement. Here's one way I use https://github.com/guest271314/sw-transfer-stream/blob/main/background.js#L70-L115. I'm using  `event.resultingClientId` in the code, which can be an empty string; `event.clientId` is always defined in the code I have tested.